# How to ignore all websocket connections with mitmproxy?

Tags: python, proxy, websocket, mitmproxy

At the moment, mitmproxy doesn't seem to be able to handle websocket connections.

How can I just pass these on so that clients can still connect with a websocket server?

Here's my current command:

[image: ./mitmproxy --anticache -s injectScripts.py]

Specifically, in my case, I'd *currently* like clients using my proxy to be able to play games on [agar.io](http://agar.io/), which uses a websocket connection to communicate with a (for our purposes, random) server which hosts the game.

Examples of game-hosting servers which agar.io connects to: *ws://151.80.96.51:1515*, *ws://37.187.171.110:1523*, *ws://37.187.163.130:1518*.

**I've already tried** using mitmproxy's [Ignore Domains](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/features/passthrough.html) feature (both from the command line and from within the program), as well as their recommended [TCP Proxy](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/features/tcpproxy.html#tcpproxy) feature. This was the pattern I tried using:

[image: ./mitmproxy --anticache -s injectScripts.py --ignore ^agar.io$]

But this just stops agar.io from loading at all (grey background, correct document title but that's it).

I think that because the client is connecting to different servers (not *ws://agar.io*) I can't use a simple domain ignore, but I may be wrong.

---

While at the moment I'm only interested in agar.io, it would be nice to have a solution for all websocket servers.

So, in short, how can I allow clients to connect to ws servers?

Comment: Well, you've mentioned yourself what you'll have to analyze (to which domains are your clients connecting via Websockets?). Do that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller But I can't ignore them on the fly, and they could always be changing. Thanks for the downvote and that insightful comment, really solves my problem.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If you know a way to ignore constantly-changing domains on-the-fly then please share, it would instantly become the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using mitmproxy 0.15+, passing `--raw-tcp` should do the job. This puts all non-HTTP traffic into TCP mode automatically.

Comment: This isn't working. Get the same problem as I did before, in that the page doesn't load properly.

Comment: This does work. Just realised that the grey page was due to the stuff I was injecting into the web page. Thank you.